# How to subclass Altair Chart

Tags: altair

How to extend the `alt.Chart` class?

I am trying to create a subclass but I have problems implementing the `__new__` and `__init__` methods. I don't know if this is something related to the fact that altair charts are immutable.

This is working as expected:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'a': list('CCCDDDEEE'), 'b': [2, 7, 4, 1, 2, 6, 8, 4, 7]})

mark = alt.MarkDef(type='bar')
encoding = alt.FacetedEncoding(
        x=alt.X(field='a'),
        y=alt.Y(field='b', aggregate='average')
)
alt.Chart(data=data, encoding=encoding, mark=mark, width=500, height=500)
```

But this is not:

```
class HBarChart1(alt.Chart):
  def __init__(self, data: pd.DataFrame, encoding: alt.FacetedEncoding, mark: alt.MarkDef, width: float = 400, height:float = 500):
    super().__init__(data=data, encoding=encoding, mark=mark, width=10, height=10)

HBarChart1(data=data, encoding=encoding, mark=mark, width=500, height=500)
```

```
TypeError: HBarChart1.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'align'
```

And, finally, this is working:

```
class HBarChart2(alt.Chart):
  def __init__(self, data: pd.DataFrame, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(data=data, **kwargs)

HBarChart2(data=data, encoding=encoding, mark=mark, width=500, height=500)
```

Comment: Could you include an example of what you have tried and what error you are running into?